# Where are the Boys of Silence?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I finished Bioshock Infinite, but I failed to see the infamous Boys of Silence everybody is talking about. Did I take any shortcut? Am I blind?

Where are they supposed to appear?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Akmur, you should consider accepting Reafexus answer, if it was the sollution you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's kind of a spoiler. You probably just didn't take a close look at them. I was hoping they would be more prevalent too.

> They are in Comstock Manor. The guys with the spotlights surrounded by the George Washington masked.. people.
>
>  [image: Boys of Silence in Comstock Manor]

Comment: Thanks man, I just restarted the game in hard mode, this time I'll take a closer look

Comment: Yea. There are only like.... 5 or 6 in the whole game. I guess I missed the Voxophones explaining what they actually are.

Comment: If I recall correctly, one spawns right behind you at one point.

Comment: Yup. The only scare like that in the game. And @Akmur don't forget to accept this as the answer.

Comment: @Unionhawk I had to replace my pants at that point, *even the ones I wasn't wearing at the time*

Comment: So I totally missed them :(